# Some questions as for vue-chartjs

Tags: vue-chartjs

In Laravel 5.6 /  vuejs 2.5 application I  use vue-chartjs, but my charts looks like :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnABm.jpg
I want some more:

- having several items(artists in my case) I want to see them half-transparent, just as in first example here http://demo.vue-chartjs.org/
- having points with values shown as in first example at link above
- I need to see all labels in x-direction( I fill labels parameter ) for here
- If there source code of demo examples of link above > I searched and did not find...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should find everything you need in the documentation of chart.js and vue-chart.js

- http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/
- http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=resources

You can add rgb values as a background color to make them transparent.
You can also use gradients as its just a canvas element.

Here is a tutorial:

https://hackernoon.com/creating-stunning-charts-with-vue-js-and-chart-js-28af584adc0a?source=user_profile---------5----------------

Here is the source code of the vue-chartjs demo page:

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs-demo
(It's a bit outdated as with v3 the creation of chart components changed a bit)

---

It seems you did not filled the labels correctly.

```
{
   labels: ['Here', 'are', 'your', 'x-axis', 'labels'],
   datasets: [
     {
       label: 'artist 1',
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
       data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     },
      {
       label: 'artist 2',
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
       data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     },
   ],
 }
```